# How to store more than 255 char in MySQL database?

Tags: sql, mysql

I only get set the text field in MySQL to 255, if I want to store a data longer than 255 chars, what can I do?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Prior to MySQL 5.0.3, a [VARCHAR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html) could only store up to 255 characters.

- To store up to 65535 (64KB) characters, use a **TEXT** column.
- To store up to 16777216 (16MB ) characters, use a **MEDIUMTEXT** column.
- To store up to 4294967296 (4GB) characters, use a **LONGTEXT** column.

See the [storage requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html) section of the manual for caveats on their usage.

Versions of MySQL after 5.0.3 can store up to 65535 chars in a VARCHAR (However you cannot store more than 65535 bytes in a single row).

Comment: I have already set it to text but it takes only 247 characters. What wrong am I doing ?

Comment: Does 'TEXT' fill unused space with spaces after the string? Does it act like CHAR or VARCHAR?

Answer (score 5):

Use `TEXT` datatype:

```
CREATE TABLE t_text (value TEXT NOT NULL);

INSERT
INTO    t_text
SELECT  RPAD('', 1000, '*');

SELECT  LENGTH(value)
FROM    t_text;

---

1000
```

Answer (score 1):

Change data type to varchar.

Comment: Until v5.0.3, a varchar could only be up to 255 chars. From 5.0.3 onwards, you can have up to 65535 chars, same as a TEXT column. To go larger, you need MEDIUMTEXT (2^24 bytes) or LONGTEXT (2^32 bytes)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL 4.0 -- Maximum length storage (Bytes) for String types:

```
CHAR(255); 
VARCHAR(255); 
TINYBLOB, TINYTEXT < 2^8; 
BLOB, TEXT < 2^16; 
MEDIUMBLOB, MEDIUMTEXT < 2^24; 
LONGBLOB, LONGTEXT < 2^32;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a VARCHAR(255) **to save url link** and a user have a link with ~300 characters, under MySql 5.7.
I switch to **VARCHAR(1024)** and it works fine.