# what length to set varchar phpmyadmin mysql 500 characters

Tags: mysql

this is the options in PHPMyAdmin mysql:

```
Name    Type Documentation  Length/Values   Default     Collation   Attributes  Null    A_I Comments    Virtuality  Move column Media (MIME) type   Browser display transformation  Browser display transformation options  Input transformation    Input transformation options
```

now when i make an varchar i usaly just set it to 255 but i know this is not correct so how do i know what (lenght/values) to set it too??? i know what size a varchar can go to and that 255 is the max but lets say i have an text area and the user types 500 characters in how do i know what lengths to set my varchar

thank you and stay safe with covid 19

Comment: How should we know? You're the only person who can determine what sort of values you can expect / want to accept... This like asking somebody to name your child for you ;)

Comment: lol  good one i mean lets say they type in 500 characters

Comment: Refer to my previous comment; it hasn't changed

Comment: Set it based on your needs, and add validation logic on the app that enforces it. It may be better to use a `TEXT` column, in spots.

Comment: well that what i am asking lets say i only want a limit of 500 characters how do i type that into the lenght/values area

Comment: no what i have read varchar is better than text

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings can you please explain this to me a mysql mediumtext can take upto 16,777,215 bytes but in my database it only takes 9811 characters utf-8 why???

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings, not medium text I mean text

Comment: That's a completely different question than you asked. Why do you think it "only takes 9811 characters"? What do you see? Be _exact_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends which value you're getting from the inputbox, imagine you've set the maximum text characters of you inputbox at 10 then you can set a varchar of 10

Just put in the length of the maximum expected value.

Comment: ok so lol 255 is not the limit?

Comment: You can find more info about this at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476987/how-to-store-more-than-255-char-in-mysql-database

Comment: okay thanks this sq very helpful @Alpha.Ars

Comment: You're welcome, Don't forget to validate my answer if you think its the right answer to your question.

Comment: yes i can in 2 minutes